# PHP json_decode with curl returning Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to define different search strings for my Cloudant db. But there is a problem in my curl function. Do you see anything wrong?

```
function get_results($url, $bookmark = NULL, $results = array()){
   $username = 'name';
   $password = 'pw';

   $url = $bookmark !== NULL ? $url."&bookmark=$bookmark" : $url;

   $ch = curl_init();
   $timeout = 5;
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
   $r = curl_exec($ch);

   curl_close($ch);

   $response = json_decode($r);

   if(count($response->rows) === 200){
       foreach($response->rows as $row){
           $results[] = $row->doc;
       }
       return get_results($url, $response->bookmark, $results);
   } else {
       foreach($response->rows as $row){
           $results[] = $row->doc;
       }
       return $results;
   }
}
```

I resceive this warnings/notices:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\... on line 62

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\... on line 68

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\... on line 68
```

Line 62 is: if(count($response->rows) === 200){

Line 68 is: foreach($response->rows as $row){

Thanks!

Comment: Learn basic __debugging__.

Comment: Have you checked the value of $response to make sure that it contains the properties you're trying to access. The errors are telling you that you're trying to access a property that doesn't exist. For example, $response->rows, it's telling you that 'rows' doesn't exist in $response. Try print_r($response) after you've set the value of $response.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Its empty. On my Laptop is the same PHP version and the same xamp version and it works, but not on the pc -.- I dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

## Safe solution

1. Download the latest cacert.pem from [libcurl official site](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).
2. Edit `curl.cainfo` in php.ini and reboot server.
   Or just configure using `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option.

Set permanently in php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo="/path/to/cacert.pem"
```

Set temporarily in PHP code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');
```

Answer (score -1):

Use following header option in your curl, will return json object:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Because default accept type is Text/Plain so it will return you parsed sting. By setting above header you will receive json object.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the same notices

Comment: Then you might no have json response

Comment: And also you may have to remove json_decode as we have set json type already

Comment: tried adding headers as well as removing the json_decode as well. no help

Answer (score -1):

I got it! The problem was the ssl certificate. I disabled it with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and now i get my response!

Comment: Do you know what you are actually doing? You are sending username and password **in untrusted path**. Please refer to [***Man-in-the-middle attack***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack)